# Setting status code in grpc server method call

Tags: go, grpc

How do I set the response status code in a grpc method in golang.  For example lets say I have the following grpc method

```
func (i *ItemServerImp) Register(ct context.Context, it *item.RegisterItemRequest) (*item.RegisterItemReply, error) {
}
```

How do I set the response status to 200 or a 400 based on the input or some processing. I had a look around and could not find a proper way to do this.

However I did find the following https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/refs/heads/chromium-deps/2016-07-27/doc/statuscodes.md which says the status code can be set.

Comment: You can refer to [this code](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/0bd92bd060aa09d31b9a7ff48815e3326c57f0b7/runtime/errors.go#L36) about the mapping with HTTP status code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a gRPC error using the [google.golang.org/grpc/status](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/status) package as follows:

```
return nil, status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "Incorrect request argument")
```

The different status codes are available in the [google.golang.org/grpc/codes](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/codes) package.